# Does GRUB format your ESP?

Tags: arch-linux, windows, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

I am installing Arch Linux on my laptop that came preinstalled with Windows 10 and after several times of restarting, I realised that you needed to install a bootloader because pacstrap doesn't do it. I installed grub using the following:

```
grub-install --efi-partition=/efi
```

But I fear that my EFI partition will be formatted and that Windows won't boot.
I am an expert at most of Linux, but I have never installed Arch.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I cannot give you a thorough answer, but I can assure you that installing GRUB on existing EFI partition does not format it. I have installed Arch on my laptop alongside Windows 10 and it worked flawlessly. The GRUB automatically recognize the Windows efi and added it to the boot list.

By the way for a reference, I installed the GRUB by doing these commands

```
$ grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --bootloader-id=GRUB --efi-directory=/path/to/efi
$ grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

No, `grub-install` does not format the ESP. The ESP must be already mounted.

`grub-install` does overwrite `grubx64.efi` (variants exist depending on architecture).